# FileConveyor - cumulus - Files not showing up on CloudFiles

Tags: cloudfiles, django-storage

I've installed FileConveyor and django cumulus (which is the replacement for mosso). I created a test directory at `/home/drupal/conveyortest` which I use as the scanPath.

When I start the FileConveyor daemon, I'm told that the js and css files are being sync'd (and deleted). When I look on my CloudFiles container, I see the `static/views_slideshow_galleria` folder has been created, but there are no files inside it. There should be one css file and one js file, but there are none.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- WARNING  - Created 'cumulus' transporter for the 'cloudfiles' server.
- WARNING  - Deleted '/home/drupal/conveyortest/views_slideshow_galleria/views_slideshow_galleria.css' as per the 'CSS, JS, images and Flash' rule.
- WARNING  - Synced: '/home/drupal/conveyortest/views_slideshow_galleria/views_slideshow_galleria.css' (CREATED).
- WARNING  - Deleted '/home/drupal/conveyortest/views_slideshow_galleria/views_slideshow_galleria.js' as per the 'CSS, JS, images and Flash' rule.
- WARNING  - Synced: '/home/drupal/conveyortest/views_slideshow_galleria/views_slideshow_galleria.js' (CREATED).
- WARNING  - Synced: '/home/drupal/conveyortest/views_slideshow_galleria/views_slideshow_galleria.css' (DELETED).
- WARNING  - Synced: '/home/drupal/conveyortest/views_slideshow_galleria/views_slideshow_galleria.js' (DELETED).
```

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <!-- Sources -->
  <sources ignoredDirs="CVS:.svn">
    <source name="drupal" scanPath="/home/drupal/conveyortest" documentRoot="/home/drupal/conveyortest" basePath="/" />
  </sources>

  <!-- Servers -->
  <servers>
    <server name="cloudfiles" transporter="cumulus">
      <username>myusername</username>
      <api_key>myapikey</api_key>
      <container>FileConveyorTest</container>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <!-- Rules -->
  <rules>
    <rule for="drupal" label="CSS, JS, images and Flash">
      <filter>
        <extensions>ico:js:css:gif:png:jpg:jpeg:svg:swf</extensions>
      </filter>
      <processorChain>
        <processor name="filename.SpacesToDashes" />
      </processorChain>
      <destinations>
        <destination server="cloudfiles" path="static" />
      </destinations>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</config>
```

Comment: this seems to be an issue with fileconveyor, see [#108](https://github.com/wimleers/fileconveyor/issues/108), and has been fixed on [systemseed's](https://github.com/wimleers/fileconveyor/issues/108#issuecomment-6229606) [fork](https://github.com/systemseed/fileconveyor/commit/68c40ebaad532d330d7dcd14271ad1cdb3c7007b)